# Why and how RefObject pass into custom hook automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm using several hooks, which applies + - the same logic of the hook usage. But hook on the target element didn't pass the ref of this element through props(parameters) of this hook.

Simplified hook code:

```js
const useHook = () => {
    const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!containerRef.current) throw new Error('container is not defined'); 
        console.log(containerRef.current) // => and here we will have a reference to the element. Why?
        
        /*some logic*/
    }, []);

    return containerRef;
}
```

Usage of this hook:

```js
export const TestComponent = () => {
    const hookRef = useHook();

    return <div ref={hookRef}>/*smth else*/</div>
}
```

Why we create ref, like `const hookRef = useHook()`?

I'm used to use eventListeners in js like that:

```
function handler(event) {}
element.addEventListener("click", handler)
```

In the abovementioned code with event listener we pass `event` into callback automatically, right? We also can write following code and the results will be the same(on a cursory examination):

```js
function handler(event) {}
element.addEventListener("click", (event) => handler(event))
```

Right.

But if we were able to do this, then we can do that:

```js
export const TestComponent = () => {
    const hookRef = useHook();

    return <div ref={el => hookRef(el)}>/*smth else*/</div>
}
```

But no.. We can't. (Yes, I understand, that in the hook function we have no parameters, but, again, **how this ref pass into the hook?**).

What I need to know to understand this hook/useRef logic? Will be glad to every your answear, thanks a lot.

**EDIT** 
But what if I need to use 2 hooks using refs on the 1 element? Like following:

```js
export const TestComponent = () => {
    const hookRef1 = useHook1();
    const hookRef2 = useHook2();

    return <div ref={el => {
        hookRef1(el) // error
        hookRef2(el) // error
    }}>/*smth else*/</div>

}
```

How to use the above code correctly?

Comment: you are not returning a function, you are returning a ref object. and the attribute `ref` expects such a object. Some attributes expects specific types. numbers, string, object, name it all :)

Comment: I don't understand why you compare ref to `addEventListener` where ref is more like `querySelector`

Comment: OMG, that's it..) 
Ok, I understant that hook return value is useRef and therefore we can use it like that. 
1 more question on this topic. Check "EDIT" if you can, please

Comment: The ref is not a function, it's an object. If you want to update its value (as you do in the "Edit" section) you'd do `hookRef1.current = el`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following hook returns the `RefObject`:

```js
const useHook = () => {
    const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        /*some logic*/
    }, []);

    return containerRef; // here it is
}
```

so we can just pass variable contains `useHook()` into ref `prop` like following:

```js
const TestComponent = () => {
    const hookRef = useHook();

    return <div ref={hookRef}>/*smth else*/</div>
}
```

or we can go this way:

```js
const TestComponent = () => {
    const hookRef = useHook();
    const hookRef2 = useHook2();

    return <div ref={element => { // multiple refs
        hookRef.current = element;
        hookRef2.current = element;
    }}>
        example text
    </div>

}
```